# No longer Thumbnail blog posts

Tags: html, css, wordpress

[image]Three recent blog posts showed up thumbnail size in a section. Now they are big and go off the screen to the right. How can I make them thumbnail size again? I had this on the homepage but took it off temporarily. I was trying to add more space above this section and that's when the formatting messed up.

```
<ul class="blog-list">
 <?php 
 // the query
 $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
  // 'category_name' => 'news',
  'posts_per_page' => 2,
    )); 
    ?>
    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
     <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ); if  ( ! empty( $img_url ) ) { ?>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('folio',  array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' )); ?>
            <?php }else{  ?>
                <?php
                ob_start();
                ob_end_clean();
                $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
                $first_img = $matches [1] [0];
                if(!empty($first_img)){ ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $first_img; ?>" alt="" />
                <?php } ?>
            <?php }; ?> 
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
          </a>
       <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
     </li>
  <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); else :  endif; ?>
</ul>
```

```
    .blog-list {
      padding: 0 8px;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
    }
    .blog-list li {
      padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .blog-list a {
      position: relative;
      text-decoration: none;
      height: 600px;
    }
    .blog-list h3 {
      padding: 20px 0 10px;
      font-size: 1.9rem;
      font-family: 'Playfair Display', Arial, serif;
      color: #c9aa70;
      line-height: 2;
    }
    .blog-list p {
      padding-bottom: 1em;
    }
    .blog-list img {
      display: block;
      height: auto !important;
      width: 100%;
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    .blog-list {
      display: grid;
      grid-column-gap: 20px;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 980px) {
    .blog-list {
      padding-bottom: 25px;
     }
     .blog-list h3 {
       font-size: 2.4rem;
     }
     .blog-list a {
       display: block;
     }
     .blog-list a img {
       transition: ease all .5s;
     }
     .blog-list a:hover {
       opacity: .8;
     }
     .blog-list + footer {
       padding-bottom: 100px;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you Please see how to create a [MRE] and update your question using [edit] to include the HTML that is generated so that we can see what the CSS is being applied to? This will make it easier for us to help!

Comment: @FluffyKitten I updated it. Does it work for you now?

Comment: I don't see any change to the question? Can you include the generated HTML rather than just the PHP that is used to generate it?

Comment: @FluffyKitten I'm not totally understanding what you mean by generating the HTML..

Comment: @j08691 Could you help me with the generated HTML? or send example? I'm not fully understanding

Comment: I mean the HTML that is created by the PHP in the web page